# Excel VBA - Copy selected cells including images

Tags: vba, excel

I have a vba script that copies the selected range of cells and pastes it in the body of an email.  Within that selected range of cells is an image of my company logo.  Everything copies and pastes fine except the image. 
Is there something I need to do to the image itself, to maybe "embed" it into the worksheet so it copies along with the cells?
Or is there something I need to do in the vba script to copy the image along with the cells?

Here is the full code:

```
Sub copyObjects()
  Dim IsCreated As Boolean
  Dim PdfFile As String, Title As String, signature As String
  Dim OutlApp As Object
  Dim RngCopied As Range

Set RngCopied = Selection

' Use already open Outlook if possible
On Error Resume Next
Set OutlApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If Err Then
  Set OutlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  IsCreated = True
End If
On Error GoTo 0

' Prepare e-mail with PDF attachment
With OutlApp.CreateItem(0)

 .Display         ' We need to display email first for signature to be added
 .Subject = Title
 .To = ActiveSheet.Range("E10").Value ' <-- Put email of the recipient here or use a cell value
 .CC = "whoever@abc.com; copy@abc.com" ' <-- Put email of 'copy to' recipients here
 .HTMLBody = "Thank you for the opportunity to bid on the painting for " & ActiveSheet.Range("B9").Value & ". " & " Please read our attached proposal in it's entirety to be sure of all inclusions, exclusions, and products proposed.  Give us a call with any questions or concerns." & _
    vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    RangetoHTML(RngCopied) & _
    "Thank you," & _
    .HTMLBody      ' Adds default outlook account signature



On Error Resume Next


' Return focus to Excel's window
Application.Visible = True
If Err Then
  MsgBox "E-mail was not sent", vbExclamation
Else
' MsgBox "E-mail successfully sent", vbInformation
End If
On Error GoTo 0

End With

' Try to quit Outlook if it was not previously open
If IsCreated Then OutlApp.Quit

' Release the memory of object variable
' Note: sometimes Outlook object can't be released from the memory
Set OutlApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
    ' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
    ' Working in Office 2000-2010
  Dim fso As Object
  Dim ts As Object
  Dim TempFile As String
  Dim TempWB As Workbook

  TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

  'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
  rng.Copy
  Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
  With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

 'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
 RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
 ts.Close
 RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

 'Close TempWB
 TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

 'Delete the htm file we used in this function
 Kill TempFile

 Set ts = Nothing
 Set fso = Nothing
 Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Because the [macros] tag is reserved for its other meanings in the world of programming.  The wiki for it specifically indicates that it should not be used for MS Office / VBA and instead you should use [vba] or the application specific tag [excel-vba].

Comment: btw- I put most of this code together from various code I found on the internet using "macro" in my search terms.  The purpose of the tags here is not just so you can find questions that you may know how to answer,  but also for people to find the answer to their own questions.  So when I used up 4 tags and had one left, I decided to throw macro in there so maybe someone less studied in Wikipedia like myself, might be helped by this post.

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True
```

Before copying

Comment: I can't figure out how to implement this.  I've tried several different places withing the code with no success.  I'll update the code above with the full macro code.  can you show me where to put this line of code?

Comment: Sorry - I hadn't read your whole question.  You will likely need to play around with the HTML export part to ensure you're also capturing pictures in the range.  Have you tried exporting directly from the range rather than making a copy of it?

Comment: I may have to do that but in searching for a solution, I found an alternative that may be better than the whole HTML export function.  It's simpler but I imagine it has a downside that I am not yet aware of; using the SendKeys method to paste the clipboard in the email body.

Answer (score -1):

If it helps, I have it in a macro like this...

[image]

The macro copies the aforementioned tabs which each contain Charts and Data Cells and Macro Buttons, into a new workbook.
The CopyObjects line, ensures that ALL the data on each tab is included in the copy.  Without it, you may find that the charts and other drawn objects are excluded.

Caveat, I'm just about to post a question about an issue I have regarding this command.  For some strange reason, just one single chart label is not being copied across - very strange so, be warned - check it works correctly for you.

Nick

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.